# How to check prepaid credit card balance for free?

Tags: credit-card

My card issuer charges 1€ for each balance-check -- since the card balance is often verified prior to online transactions without fees, can I as an individual use a similar method with no additional charges?

Comment: Is the fee for "checking your balance", or particularly for "checking your balance at an ATM"?  Quite likely the card issuer will let you check your balance via their website, or a text message, or literally anything that doesn't involve the ATM network of another bank... those are the options you should inquire about.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the answer you are looking for, but if you pay for the balance once, you can then keep track of the balance yourself. Every time you use the card, you can do some math and subtract how much you spent from your known balance.

Comment: Additionally you can infer the balance from tracking your spending and reloading.... Any time your card gets declined you know the balance is less than the amount you tried to spend, if you re-load the balance is at least what you transferred to the card. After a while you'll get very close to the amount you have on the card.